# Want to set tooltip as HTML on a Vaadin Grid cell

Tags: java, grid, tooltip, vaadin

I have a Vaadin grid which shall get a tooltip with HTML.
I tried the following code, which is from a Vaadin discussion forum, but I have no idea how the Vaadin client code works and what I need to do to make the code active. As it is below, it has no effect, i.e. the description is set to <b>ZZ</b> as text.

My code is the following:

```
    private final MyGrid<KPIBusinessDisplay> overviewGrid;

    overviewGrid.getColumn("lastAlarmStatusIcon").setDescriptionGenerator(kpi -> {
        return "<b>ZZ</b>";
    });

package com.xxx.bpspkpibpcheck.view;

import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
import com.vaadin.client.TooltipInfo;
import com.vaadin.client.connectors.grid.GridConnector;
import com.vaadin.shared.ui.Connect;
import com.vaadin.shared.ui.ContentMode;

@Connect(com.xxx.bpspkpibpcheck.view.MyGrid.class)
public class MyGridConnector extends GridConnector {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public TooltipInfo getTooltipInfo(Element inElement) {
        TooltipInfo tt = super.getTooltipInfo(inElement);
        tt.setContentMode(ContentMode.HTML);
        return tt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which Vaadin version you use? setDescriptionGenerator(DescriptionGenerator<T> descriptionGenerator,
                                    ContentMode contentMode) supports ContentMode.HTML since Vaadin 8.2.

Comment: We are using `8.1.1`. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Ok, I formulated the answer based on discussion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Grid.setDescriptionGenerator(DescriptionGenerator<T> descriptionGenerator, ContentMode contentMode)
```

supports ContentMode.HTML since Vaadin 8.2. Using this method removes the need to do custom client side extension for this purpose.